# Multiplying a std::complex<T> by double via templated operator overload

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, std, operator-keyword

I want to multiplay a `std::complex<T>` by a `double`, assuming that `T operator*(const T &t, double d)` is defined. Since I need to do this for 3 different types `T`, i tried to write a template function for the operator. Here's an example with `T=float`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

template <typename T>
std::complex<T> operator*(const std::complex<T> &cd, double d) {
    return std::complex<T>(cd.real() * d, cd.imag());
}

int main() {
    std::complex<float> cf(1.0, 1.0);
    std::complex<double> cd(1.0, 1.0);
    double d = 2.0;

    std::cout << cf * d << std::endl;
    std::cout << cd * d << std::endl;
}
```

This gives the compiler error

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘std::complex<double>’ and ‘double’)
```

The reason is clear, since for `T=double` my overload clashes with the implementation in `<complex>`. First casting the right hand side to a `T` (i.e. `cf * float(d)` in the example above) is not an option, since that would introduce significant overhead for some of my datatypes.

Is there any way I can tell the compiler that it should ignore my overload for `T=double`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can tell the compiler that it should ignore my overload for T=double?

You might use SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<double, T>::value, std::complex<T>>
operator*(const std::complex<T> &cd, double d) {
    return std::complex<T>(cd.real() * d, cd.imag());
}
```

but your implementation is not coherent with regular `operator*`.

A safer way would be to introduce your own type to wrap `double`, something like:

```
struct MyWrapper { double d; };

template <typename T>
std::complex<T> operator*(const std::complex<T> &cd, MyWrapper d) {
    return std::complex<T>(cd.real() * d.d, cd.imag());
}
```

Comment: "but your implementation is not coherent with regular operator*"

What do you mean by that?

Comment: You multiply only real part. so `(0, i) * 5.` give `(0, i)` instead if `(0, 5i)`.

Comment: Oh that was just a typo :D So in that case the SFINAE implementation would be fine?

Comment: Problem I can see is if you make a library (as other might also do the "same", and you risk ODR violation).

Answer (score 1):

`std::complex` already defines an `operator *` in the form of

```
template< class T >
std::complex<T> operator*( const std::complex<T>& lhs, const T& rhs);
```

This conflicts with your own `operator *` since both functions resolve to taking a `std::complex<double>` and a `double`.

That means you really only need to define an `operator *` for `std::vector<float>` and a `double` so you can change your overload to

```
std::complex<float> operator*(const std::complex<float> &cd, double d) {
    return std::complex<float>(cd.real() * d, cd.imag());
}
```

And then

```
std::cout << cf * d << std::endl;
std::cout << cd * d << std::endl;
```

will work.

If you want to keep the overload a template function you can use SFINAE to make it not compile for the case when you have a `std::complex<double>` by using

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<double, T>, bool> = true>
std::complex<T> operator*(const std::complex<T> &cd, double d) {
    return std::complex<T>(cd.real() * d, cd.imag());
}
```

Comment: Yeah the point is keeping the template function, since I don't write to rewrite this function for 3 different T`s

Comment: @T-Rex96 Do note that this is going to lead to different results.  `(a + bi) * c == (ac + bci)` where your operator only gives `(ac + bi)`.  You can see there difference in this live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b59c7f2b181c87b5

Comment: Yeah that was just a typo, in my actual code the operator behaves as ecpected